# Best practices to manage partner users

Tags: community

I have an requirement where Partner can manage their users. Make them active , deactivate them, and change their profile. However, I couldn't find "Manage User" permission on Partner Community Login licenses profile.

How can a partner manage his Users in Salesforce Communities ?

Answer (score 4):

You can delegate user administration to external users so that they can decide who should access the community by granting the `Manage External Users` permission.

You can grant delegated external user administration rights to users with Partner Community, Gold Partner, Enterprise Administration, and Customer Portal Manager licenses.

This can be done using a custom profile or a permission set.

[Delegating External User Administration](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_DPUA.htm)

Comment: Thanks . I think, it can resolve the issue. I'll work on this and let you know it helps.  Thanks again.